# Use xts as a lookup table

Tags: r, xts, lookup-tables

Example data:

```
library(xts)
a <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00:00"), by = 600, length.out = 3)
b <- c(a, a)
lu <- xts(seq_along(a), a)
lu[b]

                    [,1]
2010-01-01 00:00:00    1
2010-01-01 00:10:00    2
2010-01-01 00:20:00    3
```

How can one "look up" the values of `lu` for timestamps in `b` such that one gets e.g. an xts object with the same length as `b`, in this case:

```
                    [,1]
2010-01-01 00:00:00    1
2010-01-01 00:10:00    2
2010-01-01 00:20:00    3
2010-01-01 00:00:00    1
2010-01-01 00:10:00    2
2010-01-01 00:20:00    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) index by name** xts is not really the right package to do this since your desired result cannot be a valid xts object.  Instead try the following which does not use any packages.  The names of the output vector are character representations of the times and the vector values themselves are the desired values:

```
lutable <- setNames(seq_along(a), a)
lutable[format(b)]
```

giving:

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-01-01 00:10:00 2010-01-01 00:20:00 2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-01-01 00:10:00 2010-01-01 00:20:00 
                  1                   2                   3                   1                   2                   3
```

**2) match** Another possibility is just use `match` like this.  The result is the values that correspond to the times in `b`:

```
v <- seq_along(a) # test values
v[match(b, a)]
## [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: ad 1) xts objects can contain duplicate time stamps, but I think you meant the semantics would be questionable in this case. Ad 2) this is what I ended up using in with a `data.frame` a la `df[match(b,a),]`. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yes, xts objects can have duplicate time stamps but that is not really relevant because they still can't represent your desired output since they are always ordered.

Comment: Ah, yes, I checked the ordering, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor issue with the result that you expect; XTS orders the timestamp by default. So the results of an XTS object will be 1,1,2,2,3,3.

The following can give you some insight:

```
lu[match(b, index(lu))] #XTS object returned - Timestamps are ordered by default 
data.frame(ts = index(lu), lu) [match(b, index(lu)),] #Using dataframes instead reproduce the expected result.
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know and the `data.frame` example. So `xts` is really not the right tool for this.